# Removing properties from PropertyInfo[]

Tags: c#, reflection

What is the simplest way of removing first four properties from 'properties'. Where properties is PropertyInfo collection as shown below.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = GetAllPropertyForClass(className);

public static PropertyInfo[] GetAllPropertyForClass(string className) {
    Type[] _Type = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyAdapter)).GetTypes();

    return _Type.SingleOrDefault(
                t => t.Name == className).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);   
}
```

Of course I can loop through and build one more PropertyInfo[] collection by ignoring property based on its index or name. But I want to know if there is any way to achieve without looping through the properties.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: why skip the first four?

Comment: I have to build controls for properties except for the initial four properties for which controls already exist.

Comment: How are you sure it is the first four that you need to skip? I would try to filter them out by that fact instead of skipping the first 4.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can ignore fetching those 4 properties based on the name in GetAllPropertyForClass method?

Comment: @San: I've extended my answer to provide a solution that filters by name.

Comment: @Heinzi: nice of you to do that! +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ helps:

```
PropertyInfo[] almostAllProperties = properties.Skip(4).ToArray();
```

This works for all kinds of IEnumerables, not only arrays of PropertyInfo.

---

**EDIT**: As others have pointed out, excluding properties by name is more robust. Here's how you'd do that with LINQ:

```
PropertyInfo[] almostAllProperties = properties.Where(
    p => p.Name != "ExcludeProperty1"
        && p.Name != "ExcludeProperty2"
        && p.Name != "ExcludeProperty3").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyInfo[] filteredProperties = new PropertyInfo[properties.Length - 4];

for( int i = 4, x = 0; i < properties.Length; i++, x++ )
{
    filteredProperties[x] = properties[i];
}
```

This is probably the cheapest way in terms of clock cycles, although nothing fancy.

Unless this is just test code, you should never count on the first four properties being the same. Reflection doesn't guarantee sequence.

Comment: If reflection doesn't guarantee sequence. For this case do you think ignoring the properties based on the property name is the only way?

Comment: @San - perhaps defining a list of properties to ignore would be the best approach. That way, you aren't dependent on sequence or the number of properties which you want to ignore. You could also make that list driven off of a configuration file or database.

Comment: @San - FYI, reflected member sequences aren't completely random (meaning, they don't change with every invocation), but there is nothing to guarantee their sequence after recompiles, runtime changes, etc. Thus, I wouldn't advise building business logic on the assumption that the order will not change.